# jpegoptim vs jpegtran vs mozjpeg

Tags: jpeg, libjpeg-turbo, jpegoptim, jpegtran, mozjpeg

I found two slightly conflicting blog posts on this matter, here I summarize:

- [jpegoptim and jpegtran perform identically and produce identical results, while mozjpeg takes twice as long for very marginal filesize savings](https://blarg.co.uk/blog/comparison-of-jpeg-lossless-compression-tools)
- [mozjpeg takes approx 1.7* the compute time and results in a roughly proportional benefit in filesize savings compared to jpegtran](https://blog.cloudflare.com/experimenting-with-mozjpeg-2-0/)

Adding to confusion, this 
[Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1zx1wt/new_mozilla_jpeg_encoder_called_mozjpeg_that/cfxrza6) suggests that mozjpeg uses the same algorithm used in jpegcrush, and that jpegcrush is a wrapper for jpegtran... so we've come full circle? I can only assume that those Reddit comments are wrong, can anyone confirm that?

Comment: As you can read from [JPGCrush description](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=3610.0) and from [that article](https://techcrunch.com/2014/03/05/mozillas-new-jpeg-encoder-promises-up-to-10-reduction-in-file-sizes/), JPGCrush is a Perl wrapper around `jpegtran` that exercises several JPEG compression options (listed in `jpeg_scan_rgb.txt` – each line is a [`jpeg_scan_info`](https://github.com/cloudflare/jpegtran/blob/570e8e87c8c618ff028e60eb84eaa816a3fe6b40/jpeglib.h#L198) structure) and chooses the smallest output. And `mozjpeg` follows the same algorithm.

Comment: Just found the answer to your question [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8142893#up_8143648): 
_jpegcrush/jpegrescan trick: tweaks details of progressive JPEG for maximum compression (each scan gets its own Huffman table, and JPEG can arbitrarily divide data into scans)_. Also found [scans file description](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/blob/v3.1/wizard.txt#L113).

Answer (score 14):

MozJPEG library uses one algorithm inspired by `jpegcrush` (optimized progressive scans), but technically it's a completely new implementation.

MozJPEG library is a drop-in replacement for the popular libjpeg, so almost every JPEG-related tool can be compiled in "regular" and "MozJPEG" flavors.

There exists a "regular" `jpegtran` and a MozJPEG version of `jpegtran`. That's the same program, but the MozJPEG version has different default settings and performs extra work to compress better.

Similarly, `jpegoptim` is usually built with stock libjpeg, but it's also possible to build it with MozJPEG's version of libjpeg (e.g. [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac) does it).

---

There are two ways to use MozJPEG:

1. lossless (take an existing JPEG file and make it a bit smaller). That's what MozJPEG's `jpegtran` does.
2. lossy (create a new JPEG file from uncompressed pixels, with higher quality/filesize ratio). That's what MozJPEG's `cjpeg` does, and other tools like `jpegoptim` can be made to do with MozJPEG.

Both modes of operation are slower than vanilla non-optimizing libjpeg. Lossless optimization does less work, but also achieves smaller gain.

More precise speed analysis is here: https://libjpeg-turbo.org/About/Mozjpeg

Note that "slow" here is relative. In absolute terms it compresses several megapixels per second, so it may be fast enough for most applications.